# Understanding the usage of だらけ

Tags: word-usage, compounds

I've come across this in the following sentence:

> 油断だらけのこの背中

油断 means "reckless" or "negligence" and だらけ means "full of" or "riddle with".
While I can decipher(?) the meaning of the sentence as a whole to mean "This back full of openings" or something like but I can't fathom the meaning of the combination 油断だらけ.

Is it simply "Riddled with negligence"? Can I use だらけ with other words like 穴 to say that something is riddle with holes or 虫刺されだらけ to say that something is riddle with bites from insects?

Thanks

Comment: だらけ is listed as a suffix in Jisho, so I don't see why not.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel What I'm asking is if I got the usage right? Does it actually convey what I think it does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as the literal translation goes, yes, it is simply "this back riddled with negligence". Grammatically, -だらけ is a suffix that forms a no-adjective. Like "riddled with ～", "～だらけ" is used with many undesirable (and usually countable) things, like so:

- 欠点だらけの人
- 傷だらけの顔
- この文章は漢字の間違いだらけだ。
- 穴だらけのセキュリティー

A 背中 doesn't "have" 油断, and 油断 is not really countable, so 油断だらけの背中 sounds like a little poetic/literary expression to me.

On the other hand, these are incorrect:

- <sup>❌</sup>水だらけのプール (say 水でいっぱいのプール instead)
- <sup>❌</sup>笑顔だらけの顔 (say 笑顔でいっぱいの顔 instead)